# How to fix - "No module named 'pandas'" in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, conda

Activated env

```
conda activate ./env
```

Install pandas

```
conda install pandas
```

Run file

```
import pandas as pnd
```

Error

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'pandas'
```

Information about host

python -V
Python 3.8.5

conda info
active environment : /Users/a/eduсation/m/project_1/env
active env location : /Users/a/eduсation/m/project_1/env
shell level : 2
user config file : /Users/a/.condarc
populated config files :
conda version : 4.9.1

Colleagues, how to fix this? I tried to install through pip, pip3, changed activated environment from 'env folder' to base in conda, nothing helped...

Comment: How are you running your file (i.e. through typing `python <filename>` in the command line, is it a jupyter notebook,...)?

Comment: python and Jupyter notebook. Same result...

Comment: does `which python` point to the version from the conda env?

Answer (score 0):

There are three main reasons for this error:

1. Python module is not installed
2. Conflict between package and module names
3. Dependency conflict between Python modules

So, check that the module is properly exported and imported, check the name of the package i.e: correct spelling.
Try to solve the conflicts if they exist.

Comment: conda list - show me list with:
pandas                    1.1.3            py38hb1e8313_0